# How do I display a dict without "/n" but with spaces included in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

My output looks like:

```
I get the following output :
"logs": "\nplugin: Shell, id: com.test.test.plugin.Shell, version:\n" 

this is what is expected:(without displaying \n)
"logs": " plugin: Shell, id: com.test.test.plugin.Shell, version: "

How do I display a dict without "/n"
```

The code snippet is as follows:

**First we retrieve the unicode string object through a rest call.**

```
results = requests.get(url)
```

**We store this in a dict like this:**

```
value = {"result": "FAULTED", 
  "status": "CLOSED", 
  "status_message": "SUCCESS"}
newlogData = str(logData)
value['logs'] = newlogData
return value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert string value by using method `replace(old_sequence, new_sequence)`. I.e.:

```
d = {"a": "this\nis\nan\nexample", "b": "And \nthis\is\nanother example"}
for k,v in d.items():
  d[k] = v.replace("\n", " ")
```

result in:

```
{'a': 'this is an example', 'b': 'And  this\\is another example'}
```